# chrome extension time life, task in background

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, background-process, google-chrome-app

ok Hello ;), I have my chrome extension what have this manifest:

```
   "browser_action":
  {
    "default_icon": "cafe.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },


   "background": 
   {
      "scripts": ["background.js"]
   },


"permissions": 
   [
      "tabs",
      "webRequest",
      "http://*/",
      "background"
   ]
```

I want a extension that keep running  when i close its pop up page (like as blocking popups apps, something happens but you can't see). I what to preserve a task running no matter is I closed the popup page or  open it, no metter if I touch the browser_action icon constantly to open and close the EXTENSION.

I thought that with background page (JS) I would do that, but nop doesn't work like this. when i close my pop up htnl, do click out side of my app, close the app, my background page  stops, I cant save data and time Intervals (setInterval(functions())) task are destroyed.

specifically ¿what do I want?:
i what to in a pop up page save a string (like a name), close the pop up and keep it  (in background js if is possible), for again open the app see the data and edit this or something it.  AND! have a constant task running, example: like a counter increasing (I thought this part use Javascript Intervals set and clear).

Note: i am calling background script in my default html_popUP directly, i dont know if is the best practice but its work XD

Comment: `background` is what you want. You are probably running into issues with [event page version](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages) of the background page though.

Comment: Is this is indeed your manifest, then your `background.js` must be ticking along even if you close Chrome (unless the user disallowed Chrome running in background), and in any case it will run throughout the Chrome lifetime. As abraham said, you probably also have `"persistent": "false"`

Answer (score 2):

"i am calling background script in my default html_popUP directly" - 
If you link the "background.js" in "popup.html" with  element' you create two instances of background.js. For example - if you create in "backround.js" context menu - it will create two identical items in the context menu.
This is worng way to do this. To contact between popup and backround you need use [chrome.runtime.sendMessage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-sendMessage) and [chrome.runtime.onMessage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onMessage).

(I'm sorry about my english).

Answer (score 1):

on target! this was my solution:

1) Do a JS for you html popUP and use
   var  bkg = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();

2) with this you can call to background page (is like a send a messenger, yours background page and yours script are two things different)
with the variable bkg you can call functions of yours background page

3) and finally this functions have to be declared and implemented in your background page. all you do in BGPAGE It will be done behind the scenes.

this is the code:

```
//JS FROM POPUP HTML...

function connectExtension()
{
    var bkg     = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();
    var user    = document.getElementById("Usuario").value;
    var password    = document.getElementById("Clave").value;


    bkg.startExtension(user,password);

}

//and this is the BACKGROUNDPAGE

function startExtension(user,password) {


 //whatever you want to do 
    validateUser(user,password);
```

}

Comment: This is not an optimal solution since it won't work with [Event pages](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages). Messaging, as Elad mentions, is a better way.